# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'target

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, grid-search

I get the error an **"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'target'"** when executing the `grid.fit()` command. I am not sure what this means and how to fix it. Can anybody advise?

```
#Grid Search Parameter Tuning
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# datasets
dataset = np.random.rand(1000,2)

#Ridge regression 
alphas = np.array([1,0.1,0.01,0.001,0.0001,0])
model = Ridge()
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=dict(alpha=alphas))
grid.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)
```

Comment: Since you generate dataset manually using numpy, you just need to pass generated data to the fit method. Additionally, you need to generate y-values, .e.g. `y = np.random.rand(1000)`, and then call `grid.fit(dataset, y)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given created random array as your dataset, you are passing that data set in fit but that data does not have target, you need to define another array which define labels.

```
x = np.random.rand(1000,2)
y3 = np.concatenate((np.zeros(500),np.ones(500)))
random = np.random.permutation(1000)
y = y3[random]
```